# Morphism induced in cohomology of a covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, surfaces, covering-spaces

It is a basic question but I'm stuck.

If $p:M\rightarrow N$ is a $m$-fold unramified covering between surfaces, why the morphism induced by $p$ in cohomology at level 2 with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/m$ is zero?

Comment: Show that if $U$ is a small open subset in $N$ which is well-covered by $p$, there is a generator of $H^2(N)$ which vanishes on all simplices contained in $N-U$. Show that the pullback of such a generator by $p$ is zero, because it is the sum of $m$ $2$-cocycles on $M$, each of represent the same generator of $M$ (I'm assuming everything to be oriented for some reason here…)

Answer (score 1):

An $m$-fold covering map $p$ has degree $m$, so $p^* : H^2(N; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(M; \mathbb{Z})$ is given by multiplication by $m$. There is a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H^2(N; \mathbb{Z}) @>{p^*}>> H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})\\
@VVV @VVV \\
H^2(N; \mathbb{Z}_m) @>>> H^2(M;\mathbb{Z}_m)
\end{CD}$$

where the vertical maps are coefficient reduction modulo $m$, and the second horizontal arrow is the one you asked about.

If $N$ and $M$ are not closed, then $H^2(N; \mathbb{Z}_m) = H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}_m) = 0$ (and hence the map between them is zero). From now on, suppose $N$ and $M$ are closed.

If $N$ and $M$ are orientable, then each vertical map is the quotient map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_m$. So the map $H^2(N; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}_m)$ obtained by going clockwise is zero, and therefore so is the counterclockwise map. As the map $H^2(N; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(N; \mathbb{Z}_m)$ is surjective, the map $H^2(N; \mathbb{Z}_2) \to H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ must be zero.

If $M$ is not orientable, then $H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}_m) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ if $m$ is even or $0$ if $m$ is odd. In the first case, the map $H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}_m)$ is an isomorphism, and in the second case, it is the zero map. Either way, the clockwise map $H^2(N; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}_m)$ is zero, and therefore so is the counterclockwise map. Whether $N$ is orientable or not, the map $H^2(N; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}_m)$ is surjective, so as in the previous paragraph, it follows that he map $H^2(N; \mathbb{Z}_m) \to H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}_m)$ is the zero map.

---

Note, if $M$ and $N$ were manifolds of dimension $n$, the analogous statement with $2$ replaced by $n$ would also be true.

Comment: But the question is (or should be!) *why* is that map multiplication by $m$, no? :-)